# Is it possible to TCP connect to an iPhone listening on a port on a 3G network?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, networking, tcp

I'm working on an app that relies heavily on P2P, but I currently don't have any SIM cards with which to experiment so I'm testing on a wifi network.

I'd like to know if iPhones on 3G networks are connectable and whether or not I will need to traverse NAT devices.

Comment: It should be possible, but of course, you will need some form of NAT punch through if you are doing P2P. Also, traversing the 3G NATs will be more difficult if you are using TCP rather than UDP. Overall, it should be the same as a WiFi connection.

Comment: I suppose I should have specified about NAT. I was wondering if I'd have to do traversal or not. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're behind the provider's router and your IP address will be something like 10.x.x.x - so you'd have the tell the router, that a TCP connect from the internet to port 9420 should be forwarded to your device. I doubt that they will do this for you.